# How to hide the maximize and minimize button and show the close button in a qml application window?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I  tried flags:

```
ApplicationWindow 
{
    id:window
    visible:true
    flags: Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | ~Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint. 
}
```

When I do this maximize, minimum and close button gets removed. I want to display close button. Somebody please help me to do this. How to take the negotiation of flag? Does this work in qml? 
Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint will Adds a close button.so i use the negotiation of that flag.

Comment: but Iam loading this Qml using loader

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what i have to add to this. am loading this qml using loader from another qml

Comment: can anybody help

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
ApplicationWindow 
{
    id:window
    visible:true
    flags: Qt.Dialog
}
```